# How to implement multiple serializers using kryo in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, hazelcast, kryo

I have an existing domain model which I would like not to change to work with Hazelcast. For this, I want to use StreamSerializer interface and Kryo. I have taken a look at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-book-examples/blob/master/chapter-serialization/kryo-serializer/src/main/java/PersonKryoSerializer.java example (or similar http://blog.hazelcast.com/2013/10/16/kryo-serializer/), but I wonder how to go ahead and add some more serializers for other classes.

Is it advisable to create a new `StreamSerializer` class, again with the `ThreadLocal` construct? This means, that again a new Kryo object will be created, is this ok? Or is it better to have only 1 `Kryo` object in the whole application?

Some of the classes do not have default constructors, how do I fit that in?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for creating a superclass holding the Kryo objects (and the thradlocal) and create a subclass per entity above it.

Comment: How do you see this possible with a superclass given the ThreadLocal field is static?

Comment: package private or public static?